# Can someone identify this vine? It is growing up and wrapped around the canopy of a tree

Tags: identification, trees, tree-care, vines, urban-gardening

[image]It is about the size of my wrist.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEDuP.jpg)

Comment: Clues such as your location on the globe, etc are important to an accurate answer. A closer picture would be helpful too. Strange fine, though.